# BeautifulSoup extract multiple elements from a class

Tags: beautifulsoup

I've been trying to web scrape the links of the images from a site but I only ever manage to get the first link.

code:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests


def getimg(link):
    source = requests.get(link).text
    soup = BeautifulSoup(source, 'lxml')
    imglist = soup.find_all('div', class_='container-chapter-reader')
    for links in imglist:
         imglink = links.find('img').get('src')
         print(imglink)

getimg('https://manganelo.com/chapter/kimetsu_no_yaiba/chapter_1')
```

output:

```
https://s9.mkklcdnv6tempv4.com/mangakakalot/k1/kimetsu_no_yaiba/chapter_1_cruelty/1.jpg
```

a short snippet of the HTML:

```
<div class="container-chapter-reader">
<img src="https://s9.mkklcdnv6tempv4.com/mangakakalot/k1/kimetsu_no_yaiba/chapter_1_cruelty/1.jpg" alt="Kimetsu no Yaiba Chapter 1 : Cruelty page 1 - MangaNelo.com" title="Kimetsu no Yaiba Chapter 1 : Cruelty page 1 - MangaNelo.com" />
<img src="https://s9.mkklcdnv6tempv4.com/mangakakalot/k1/kimetsu_no_yaiba/chapter_1_cruelty/2.jpg" alt="Kimetsu no Yaiba Chapter 1 : Cruelty page 2 - MangaNelo.com" title="Kimetsu no Yaiba Chapter 1 : Cruelty page 2 - MangaNelo.com" />
<img src="https://s9.mkklcdnv6tempv4.com/mangakakalot/k1/kimetsu_no_yaiba/chapter_1_cruelty/3.jpg" alt="Kimetsu no Yaiba Chapter 1 : Cruelty page 3 - MangaNelo.com" title="Kimetsu no Yaiba Chapter 1 : Cruelty page 3 - MangaNelo.com" />
<img src="https://s9.mkklcdnv6tempv4.com/mangakakalot/k1/kimetsu_no_yaiba/chapter_1_cruelty/4.jpg" alt="Kimetsu no Yaiba Chapter 1 : Cruelty page 4 - MangaNelo.com" title="Kimetsu no Yaiba Chapter 1 : Cruelty page 4 - MangaNelo.com" />
<img src="https://s9.mkklcdnv6tempv4.com/mangakakalot/k1/kimetsu_no_yaiba/chapter_1_cruelty/5.jpg" alt="Kimetsu no Yaiba Chapter 1 : Cruelty page 5 - MangaNelo.com" title="Kimetsu no Yaiba Chapter 1 : Cruelty page 5 - MangaNelo.com" />
```

This continues for as many times as there are images.

Comment: Shouldn't you be using find_all instead of find to get the list of images ?

Comment: @Anonymous that only returns : "AttributeError: ResultSet object has no attribute 'get'. You're probably treating a list of elements like a single element. Did you call find_all() when you meant to call find()?"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this example how to return list of images from this page:

```py
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup


def getimg(link):
    source = requests.get(link).text
    soup = BeautifulSoup(source, "lxml")

    rv = []
    for img in soup.select(".container-chapter-reader > img"):
        rv.append(img["src"])

    return rv


images = getimg("https://manganelo.com/chapter/kimetsu_no_yaiba/chapter_1")
print(*images, sep="\n")
```

Prints:

```
https://s9.mkklcdnv6tempv4.com/mangakakalot/k1/kimetsu_no_yaiba/chapter_1_cruelty/1.jpg
https://s9.mkklcdnv6tempv4.com/mangakakalot/k1/kimetsu_no_yaiba/chapter_1_cruelty/2.jpg
https://s9.mkklcdnv6tempv4.com/mangakakalot/k1/kimetsu_no_yaiba/chapter_1_cruelty/3.jpg
https://s9.mkklcdnv6tempv4.com/mangakakalot/k1/kimetsu_no_yaiba/chapter_1_cruelty/4.jpg
https://s9.mkklcdnv6tempv4.com/mangakakalot/k1/kimetsu_no_yaiba/chapter_1_cruelty/5.jpg
https://s9.mkklcdnv6tempv4.com/mangakakalot/k1/kimetsu_no_yaiba/chapter_1_cruelty/6.jpg
https://s9.mkklcdnv6tempv4.com/mangakakalot/k1/kimetsu_no_yaiba/chapter_1_cruelty/7.jpg
https://s9.mkklcdnv6tempv4.com/mangakakalot/k1/kimetsu_no_yaiba/chapter_1_cruelty/8.jpg
https://s9.mkklcdnv6tempv4.com/mangakakalot/k1/kimetsu_no_yaiba/chapter_1_cruelty/9.jpg

...and so on.
```